# Load Detailed Data On Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner at android. I have made a viewpager with two fragments. I have some recycler view item in the first fragment. One recyclerview item will fill a fragment. on swipe to next fragment can I load the details of the recycler view item which i have swiped. or how to pass the position of the recyclerview item to next fragment on swipe please help.

Answer (score 1):

well you can do this solution:

- first you should send data from your first fragment to your
  activity: to send data to your activity you can implement an interface inside your activity and call it inside the fragment when you want to pass data:
  [Android Passing Data Between Fragments](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments)
- second you should send the data from activity to your second fragment when user swiped the viewpager: you can implement an interface inside your second fragment and call it inside of onPageSelected function :

  ```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
    positionOffsetPixels) {}

     public void onPageSelected(int position) {
     // Check if this is the page you want.
     }
  });
  ```